# The meaning of "that's saying a good deal"

Tags: meaning

> "And if you thought you saw anything there, understand that there are
>   more illusions in a tinker's cart that there are in the rest of the
>   world. And **that's saying a good deal**, for it' a shadow of a dream."

This is from ”The Story of Mona Sheehy" by Lord dunsany.

I can't understand  the meaning of 
"that's saying a good deal"

I am glad if somebody strong text would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

"And that's saying a good deal" means saying a lot, or saying much.

[Merriam-Webster "good deal"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20deal)

The text you are reading looks as if it could be difficult for a learner.

Answer (score 1):

"that's saying a good deal" literally means "that's saying a lot".

Both expressions emphasize the importance or significance of what has been said, and are generally used after a sentence where one thing thing is described in with reference to another.

> Jeff Bezos is richer than Bill Gates- and that's saying a lot [about Jeff Bezos, because Bill Gates is very rich indeed].

It can also be used in the negative:

> Dewi hasn't missed as many classes as Putu, but that's not saying a lot because Putu has missed nearly every class.